# Svelte bind is not working when customElement: true is set

Tags: javascript, data-binding, svelte

I want to build a custom element using Svelte.

Thus in `rollup.config.js` I set `customElement: true`, and then I have to use the  to refer to my child components.

But I found that in this way, the `bind` will not work. Here is the code example

HelloWorld.svelte (child)

```js
<script>
    import Hello from './components/Hello'
    import World from './components/World'
    export let value;
</script>

<svelte:options tag={'x-app-helloworld'}/>
<input type="text" bind:value={value} >

<input>
<x-app-hello />
<x-app-world />
```

App.svslte(parent) part of it.

```js
<x-app-helloworld bind:value={value}/>
```

Then the parent will show an error: `'value' is not a valid binding on <x-app-helloworld> elements.`

How could I solve this `bind` problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bindings work on regular elements because Svelte knows which event corresponds to each binding — for example, it knows that the `value` of an `<input>` changes when the element fires a `change` or `input` event.

With custom elements, there's no way to know what event (if any) the parent should be listening for. And there isn't *currently* a neat way to dispatch events from inside the element. So the best option is to pass in a callback to the custom element, and call it whenever the value changes:

```html
<x-app-helloworld onValueChange="{(x) => value = x}"/>
```

```html
<script>
  export let onValueChange;
  export let value;

  $: onValueChange(value);
</script>
```

Comment: today I come across this issue with using shoe-lace UI components. I think this approach is interesting