# Using Svelte JS framework with a Web Component library, how can I accomplish two-binding with the custom elements via the bind:value directive?

Tags: ionic-framework, web-component, svelte-3, ui5-webcomponents, shoelace

**Note:** There is a GitHub issue open on the Svelte repo for this very question.
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4838
While I understand that this may or may not someday become a feature of Svelte, what I am asking is **how I can create a workaround today** to support a third-party web component library like [Shoelace](https://github.com/shoelace-style/shoelace/) or [UI5](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents), or [Ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework) with two-way binding?

**Synopsis:**

1. I have set up a Svelte app and successfully added a Web Component Library (Ex: Shoelace).
2. I write a line of code that uses two-way binding like:

   ```html
   <sl-input name="name" type="text" label="Name" bind:value={name}/>
   ```
3. I cannot two-way bind (`bind:value={}`) because the Svelte compiler doesn't recognize the valid bindings for the custom web components.

If there were a wrapper library that you know of, or some other thing I could do to make it work, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work with libraries but it is worth a shot. For my custom component I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239040/18215706) answer.

Add this in your custom component:

```
<script>
  export let onValueChange;
  export let value;

  $: onValueChange(value);
</script>
```

And add this when using the component (it will give an error until you add this)

```
<custom-component onValueChange="{(x) => value = x}"/>
```

Comment: Two things: (1) thanks for your reply, and (2) while it isn't 100% what I was looking for, that is a fairly clever, and concise workaround. I will keep this idea in mind as a backup plan. :)